# JavaScript код не работает корректно

Tags: javascript, notepad++

[image: код]

При запуске, в браузере должна выводится надпись: Hello world

Но, она не выводится

Comment: 1) Закройте тег `</body>`. 2) Смотрите результат в консоли.

Answer (score 2):

Так ты же в консоль выводиш. Открой консоль: Нажми F12 или Ctrl + shift + J, дальше вкладку Console.